# Convert bytecode type to java type

Tags: java, bytecode

I want to convert bytecode type to java using an api instead of manually coding for it, Is there any api for that? Since the requirement goes high I have to keep adding the convertion type manually which is bit tedious.

```
[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;
J[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement;
Ljava/util/Map;
Ljava/util/LinkedList;
Ljava/lang/String;
Ljava/net/URL;
Z
Ljava/lang/String;
[Ljava/net/URL;
```

Previously I used code it manually as below.

```
 private static Type getType(final char[] buf, final int off) {
    int len;
    switch (buf[off]) {
    case 'V':
        return VOID_TYPE;
    case 'Z':
        return BOOLEAN_TYPE;
    case 'C':
        return CHAR_TYPE;
    case 'B':
        return BYTE_TYPE;
    case 'S':
        return SHORT_TYPE;
    case 'I':
        return INT_TYPE;
    case 'F':
        return FLOAT_TYPE;
    case 'J':
        return LONG_TYPE;
    case 'D':
        return DOUBLE_TYPE;
 }
}
```

And when I used asm library for this,

```
Type.getArgumentTypes(desc);
```

it showed me an error as below.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 44
>       at org.objectweb.asm.Type.getArgumentTypes(Unknown Source)

Comment: I don't think you will find an API with only this feature. If you only need the type, yours is ok. You may study some decompiler code like https://github.com/java-decompiler

Comment: I am using asm and it provides some feature set for these but couldn't find a method to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a method getTypeLength:

```
private static int getTypeLength(final char[] buf, final int off) {
    switch (buf[off]) {
        case 'V':
        case 'Z':
        case 'C':
        case 'B':
        case 'S':
        case 'I':
        case 'F':
        case 'J':
        case 'D':
            return 1;
        case 'L':
        {
            int i = offs+1;
            while (buf[i] != ';') {
                ++i;
            }
            return i-offs+1;
        }
        case '[':
            return getTypeLength(buf, off+1)+1;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
private static Type getType(final char[] buf, final int off) {
    int len;
    switch (buf[off]) {
        case 'V':
            return VOID_TYPE;
        case 'Z':
            return BOOLEAN_TYPE;
        case 'C':
            return CHAR_TYPE;
        case 'B':
            return BYTE_TYPE;
        case 'S':
            return SHORT_TYPE;
        case 'I':
            return INT_TYPE;
        case 'F':
            return FLOAT_TYPE;
        case 'J':
            return LONG_TYPE;
        case 'D':
            return DOUBLE_TYPE;
        case 'L':
        {
            int len = getTypeLength(buf, offs);
            String name = new String(buf, offs+1, len-2).replace('/', '.');
            return Class.forName(name);
        }
        case '[':
            int len = getTypeLength(buf, offs);
            return Class.forName(new String(buf, offs, len));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but my requirement was I dont want to do it manually since I can't add all types and can't keep track where it might go wrong. So if I can use a api it would be easy and secure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using asm it would be like this,

```
Type.getType(desc).getClassName();
```

Type class from asm library and its static method getType which accepts a string will convert bytecode type to java type.